# error using pointers in functions c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef struct node{
    char a;
    map<char , node*> b;
}node;

node a[26] ; 

void add(string s){
    node *prev = &(a[s[0]-'a']);
    int i = 0;
    int len = s.length();
    for(i = 1; i < len; ++i){        
        map<char,node*>::iterator it = ((*prev).b).find(s[i]);
        if(it != ((*prev).b).end()){
            prev = it->second;
        }
        else{
            cout << (*prev).a << endl;
            node pt;
            pt.a = s[i];
            ((*prev).b)[s[i]] = &pt;
            prev = &pt;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    string s = "helloworld";
    string t = "htllothis";
    int i = 0 ;
    for(i = 0;i < 26;++i){
        a[i].a = 'a'+i;
    }
    add(s);
    add(t);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to implement tire datastructure using map and char but `cout<< (*prev).a` is printing some other chars. What is the mistake I have done?

Comment: What is the expected output and what output do you get?

Comment: It has to print chars of "helloworl" and "tllothis" with newline for each char but instead it is printing some garbage values.

Comment: `typedef struct node { ... } node;` is very C like. In C++, you can just simply use `struct node { ... };` as `node` is useable as is without a `typedef`.

Comment: @crashmstr that `typedef struct` crap drives me nuts, what a terrible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `(*prev).b` is equivalent to `prev->b`, I do not understand why you use `->` for iterator but not for this pointer, it is difficult to read your code.

Main problem that you insert pointer to a local object into map:

```
       cout << (*prev).a << endl;
       node pt;
       pt.a = s[i];
       ((*prev).b)[s[i]] = &pt;
       prev = &pt;
```

After leaving this block that pointer becomes invalid and you get random errors. You either should create node by operator new and better have smart pointer in your map, or keep node by value.

Answer (score 0):

```
(...)
node pt;
pt.a = s[i];
((*prev).b)[s[i]] = &pt;
prev = &pt;
(...)
```

In your `add` function you're creating a local `node` and passing its address into an entry of the map and then make it the `prev` node. Once the variable is out of scope it is deleted and your `prev` node points to an invalid address. So next time you print `prev`anything could happen as it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Yep, I thought the same thing.